# Example on how to have two Grunt configurations, one with concat and one without

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

So, I discovered the amazing power of grunt, and I like. So after concatenating many js files and uglifying them I'm saving a lot of bandwidth... great. Problem is that when developing I'd like to have them standalone (so it's easier to debug). Then when I'm ready for production I'd like to put them all in a single minified file.

I can think of many ways to do this, but, is there a best practice or some plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Use targets:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  concat: {
    dev: {
      files: [
        { src: ['src/foo/*.js'], dest: 'dist/foo.js' },
        { src: ['src/bar/*.js'], dest: 'dist/bar.js' },
      ],
    },
    prod: {
      src: ['src/**/*.js'], dest: 'dist/all.js',
    },
  },
  uglify: {
    prod: {
      src: 'dist/all.js', dest: 'dist/all.min.js',
    },
  }
});
grunt.registerTask('dev', ['concat:dev']);
grunt.registerTask('prod', ['concat:prod', 'uglify']);
```

Then run `grunt dev` when you want a development build or `grunt prod` when you want a production build.

Comment: thanks, so then in my final app will have to put fallbacks (like if all.js is not avail, let's load foo.js and bar.js)?

Comment: Yes. grunt-usemin is a tool for switching out script tags in your HTML. I personally use module bundlers (browserify, webpack, etc) and only use a single script tag (instead of concat). Then build development/production builds using targets like above.